# Use DynamoDB with Django auth

Tags: django, authentication, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use Django auth with DynamoDB. Currently i couldn't find any thing related to this.
There are Dynamorm and pynamoDB, but how can i use them for authentication in Django ?
Or there are other ways to do authentication other than auth ?